# python dataframe regex create new column from text cell

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

I have a dataframe and one of the columns contains a bunch of random text.  Within the random text is one name per row.  I would like to create a new column within the dataframe that is only the name.  All of these name start with capital letters and are preceded by phrases like, "Meet" "name is" "hello to".  I believe I should use regex but not sure beyond that.

Example texts from a dataframe cells:
"This is John.  He is a rock star on tour in Australia." (desired name is John)
"Meet Randy.  He probably has the best hairdo on planet Earth."  (desired name is Randy)
"Say hello to Mike!  His moustache won first prize at the county fair."  (desired name is Mike)

I think the code should be something like:
df['name'][df['text'].str.extract('r'____________')

Answer (score 0):

First get the regex patterns. My logic seeing your pattern is that:

1. every name starts with a capital letter,
2. has a space before the name
3. starts  has a character after the name (exclamation mark or full stop),
4. after the name has a space else even Earth will be counted, which we do not want

The regex for the following is:

```
re1='(\\s+)'                    # White Space 1
re2='((?:[A-ZÀ-ÿ][a-zÀ-ÿ]+))'   # Word 1
re3='([.!,?\\-])'               # Any Single Character 1
re4='(\\s+)'                    # White Space 2
```

I use this website to get my regex: https://txt2re.com/

Now do:

```
df['name'] = df['text'].str.extract(re1+re2+re3+re4, expand=True)[1]
```

Output:

```
0     John
1    Randy
2     Mike
3   Amélie
Name: name, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you.  This works but not for everything in the file.  I believe I need the additional qualifier of the preceding phrases described above.

Comment: With the text:  "This is Amélie.  She is a confident college girl."   (returns Sh for the name)

Comment: @CaseyO, fixed it, please check.